# How to make CORS API call from Blazor client app with authentication using AutoRest Client?

Tags: asp.net-core, cors, blazor

I am trying to call Web API from Blazor Client App. The API sends required CORS headers and works fine when I call the API using plain Javascript.

The API needs Auth cookies to be included when making a call so using JavaScript I can call:

```
fetch(uri, { credentials: 'include' })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => { console.log(data) })
        .catch(error => console.log('Failed'));
```

Now, I am trying to do the same on Blazor. I came across [this section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.0#httpclient-and-httprequestmessage-with-fetch-api-request-options) on the docs which says:

```
requestMessage.Properties[WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.FetchArgs] = new
    { 
        credentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include
    };
```

When I make a call now, it fails with following exception:

> WASM: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The provided value '2' is not a valid enum value of type RequestCredentials.

I noticed that adding following on `Statrup.cs` allows me to call API including credentials ([here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/d18a033b1ee6d923a72d440718c5d496b57c2ffc/src/Components/test/testassets/BasicTestApp/Startup.cs)):

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Create("WEBASSEMBLY")))
        {
            WebAssemblyHttpMessageHandler.DefaultCredentials = FetchCredentialsOption.Include;
        }
```

Now, I would like to call the API using `AutoRest` generated API Client so that I can reuse existing client and save lot of time. Setting `DefaultCredentials` as above doesn't work and shows following exception:

> WASM: Microsoft.Rest.HttpOperationException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError'

Setting the `requestMessage.Properties` as above, says

> The provided value '2' is not a valid enum value of type RequestCredentials`.

I am already injecting `HttpClient` from Blazor using [this technique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49953565).

Comment: I realized my HttpClient was initialized wrongly. Fiddler saved the day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really the answer... I just need space

> Setting the requestMessage.Properties as above, says The provided
>   value '2' is not a valid enum value of type RequestCredentials

If so, what is wrong with the other method I suggested, which I guess is working.

Incidentally,

> The provided value '2' is not a valid enum value of type
>   RequestCredentials

is not related to Blazor, right ? No such type (RequestCredentials) in Blazor. Perhaps your code, whatever it may be, gets the numeric value of the FetchCredentialsOption.Include and not its Enum string

Consider instantiating an HttpRequestMessage object, and configuring it according to your requirements.

Hope this helps...